# problema al ejecutar copia de seguridad con Rsync desde el Cron de Linux

Tags: linux, cron

tengo un script sencillo con el quiero hacer unos respaldos programados cada cierto tiempo. el script contiene el siguiente codigo:

```
#!/bin/bash

rsync -avhr /home/soporte/ /home/soporte/Desktop/copiaRaiz/
```

El script se llama `rsync.sh` por lo tanto le di todos los permisos con el siguiente comando: `chmod +rwx rsync.sh`.

Ahora bien, si ejecuto el script de forma manual con el comando `sh rsync.sh` se ejecuta sin problemas y copia todos los archivos de forma correcta. El problema es que cuando lo coloco en el crontab si se ejecuta pero no de la forma correcta.

El directorio que intento copiar tiene varias carpetas dentro, ejemplo: dentro de soporte hay varias carpetas: carpeta1, carpeta 2 hasta carpeta n. cuando el script se ejecuta en el cron todas esas carpetas se crean pero no se copian todos los archivos que contienen dentro, el comando lo estoy ejecutando de forma recursiva, y ese no es el problema porque cuando lo ejecuto de forma manual si se copian todos los archivos dentro de todas las carpetas.

Alguna idea de que pueda estar pasando?

Comment: el problema se puede dar por la recursion debido a que copias `/home/soporte/` pero al iniciar la copia se crea `/home/soporte/copiaRaiz/` con todo y al crearse por la recursion debe ser copiado y al ser copiado es nuevo asi que se vuelve a copiar y entra en loop y se cancela automanticamente! intenta copiarlo a otra ruta como `/home/copiaSoporte/`

Comment: el directorio destino es:  /home/soporte/Desktop/copiaRaiz/ no /home/soporte/copiaRaiz/ . Ademas, como indico en la descripcion de mi pregunta el problema ocurre unica y exclusivamente cuando el script se ejecuta desde el cron, si lo ejecuto de forma manual todos los archivos se copian correctamente. Algo pasa cuando se ejecuta desde el cron pero no encuentro cual es el problema.

Comment: el final es el mismo y se que hace el comando! pero sigue estando dentro del directorio a copiar.. por ello te recomende cambiar la ruta! ya que estas haciendo un posible loop.
el error se puede debe a que crontab no carga por defecto las `env` o algun otro posible error agrega `/usr/bin/rsync -avhr /home/soporte/ /home/soporte/Desktop/copiaRaiz/ > /dev/null 2>&1` esto forzara cualquier error a ser redireccionado y le especificas las ruta absoluta.

Comment: no funciona, no se copian todas las carpetas y al copiar algunos archivos muestra errores, no entindo por que.